# How to search for multiple elements in a dictionary that has a list as its values?

Tags: python

I have a dictionary with a list as its values.

How do I go about searching for the elements in the list that match the elements (*one or more*) that I'm looking for and retrieving the key & value pair out into a separate dictionary?

The code that I have now only allows me to search for a *single* element and stores *keys only* into the result.

```
dict = {
    "4Fingers Crispy Chicken":["Fast Food", "L1", "4Fingers Crispy Chicken"],
    "Aburi-EN":["Restaurant", "L1", "Aburi-EN"],
    "Ah Chiang's Porridge":["Eatery","B1","Ah Chiang's Porridge"],
    "BlackBall":["Dessert","B1", "BlackBall"],}
result=[]

value_to_search = input("Search:")

for key, val in dict.items():
        if value_to_search in val:
                result.append(key)
print(result)
```

Can someone educate me on how I am able to search for several elements at once and also store both key and value.

Comment: So instead of just getting the key, you want to store key, value pair as dictionary?

Comment: Your code shows that you already know how to make a dictionary and how to search the correct keys. What is your specific problem making a dictionary using these keys?

Comment: If I understood correctly, his problem is that he wants to input a `values_to_search` list instead of a single `value_to_search`.

Comment: @ShadabHussain Yes, and to be able to search for more than one element

Comment: @ypnos Yes and to store the key & value data into a dictionary

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I would like to search for multiple elements in the list and be able to store the key & value into a separate dictionary

Comment: How do you want to take input for multiple elements? In one go or through a loop? @JonathanC5915

Comment: @ShadabHussain preferably one go! Would like to learn how to do so!

Comment: @JonathanC5915 But then you should decide **separator**, since space already in use as valid value.

Comment: You can enter elements to be searched in one go splitted with `,`. then iterate through that to search for the element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dictionary comprehension with `if` filtering.

```py
dic = {
    "4Fingers Crispy Chicken": ["Fast Food", "L1", "4Fingers Crispy Chicken"],
    "Aburi-EN": ["Restaurant", "L1", "Aburi-EN"],
    "Ah Chiang's Porridge": ["Eatery", "B1", "Ah Chiang's Porridge"],
    "BlackBall": ["Dessert", "B1", "BlackBall"],
}

value_to_search = input("Search:")

result = {
    k: v for k, v in dic.items()
    if value_to_search in v
}
print(result)
```

output:

```
Search:B1
{"Ah Chiang's Porridge": ['Eatery', 'B1', "Ah Chiang's Porridge"], 'BlackBall': ['Dessert', 'B1', 'BlackBall']}
```

---

#### Note:

- Be careful with rebinding name `dict`. It's a built-in name.
- When you use trailing comma on **display** syntax, it would be better to close parenthesis(bracket, brace) at new line - except single element tuple(See second paragraph of [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#when-to-use-trailing-commas)).

---

#### Append:

> However, how would I go about searching for two values instead?

I assume that separator is `|`.

```py
value_to_search = input("Search: ")

results = {
    target: {
        k: v for k, v in dic.items()
        if target in v
    } for target in value_to_search.split('|')
}

from pprint import pprint  # just for posting readability.

pprint(results)
```

output:

```
Search: L1|B1
{'B1': {"Ah Chiang's Porridge": ['Eatery', 'B1', "Ah Chiang's Porridge"],
        'BlackBall': ['Dessert', 'B1', 'BlackBall']},
 'L1': {'4Fingers Crispy Chicken': ['Fast Food',
                                    'L1',
                                    '4Fingers Crispy Chicken'],
        'Aburi-EN': ['Restaurant', 'L1', 'Aburi-EN']}}
```

---

> I wanted to be able to search for "Fast Food" & " L1" at the same time. And pull out the key&value that matches "Fast Food" & "L1"

I misunderstood. Here is the answer.

```py
value_to_search = input("Search: ")

results = {
    k: v for k, v in dic.items()
    if all(
        target.strip() in v
        for target in value_to_search.split('&')
    )
}
```

output:

```
Search: Fast Food & L1
{'4Fingers Crispy Chicken': ['Fast Food', 'L1', '4Fingers Crispy Chicken']}
```

---

#### Explanation

- `{k: v for k, v in dic.items() if ...`
  it creates new dictionary with elements which satisfy condition.
- `all(...)`
  `all` is built-in function. You can see [reference](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#all).
  It takes an *iterable* and return True only all of the iterable's elements are `True`.
- `target.strip()`
  Remove white spaces in left and right side of target(not inside of string).
- `value_to_search.split('&')`
  Make list separated by `&` from `value_to_search`

Comment: Nice! However, how would I go about searching for two values instead?

Comment: @JonathanC5915 I updated my answer. I'm not sure that you meant **separate dictionary** means one dictionary for each queries or just different from original dictionary. In other words, do you want to **merge** or to **separate** each query result?

Comment: Sorry, I think you have mistaken what I was trying to say.
I wanted to be able to search for "Fast Food" & " L1" at the same time. 
And pull out the key&value that matches "Fast Food" & "L1".

Comment: @JonathanC5915 Sorry, I misunderstood. I updated new answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Would you mind explaining the code to me? I am new to python and do not fully understand what u have done.

Comment: @JonathanC5915 I added explanation. Feel free to comment if you need detail for specific parts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
dict = {
    "4Fingers Crispy Chicken":["Fast Food", "L1", "4Fingers Crispy Chicken"],
    "Aburi-EN":["Restaurant", "L1", "Aburi-EN"],
    "Ah Chiang's Porridge":["Eatery","B1","Ah Chiang's Porridge"],
    "BlackBall":["Dessert","B1", "BlackBall"],}
result={}

value_to_search = input("Search:")

for key, val in dict.items():
        if value_to_search in val:
                # if you want key value pair just for the element you are searching for
                result[key] = value_to_search
print(result)
```

Output:

```
Search:L1
{'4Fingers Crispy Chicken': 'L1', 'Aburi-EN': 'L1'}
```